# Remove public directory from laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

i'm making a laravel project and i have a big problem, i can't remove the /public/ name from my URL. I saw a solution that move some files of the public dir to the root dir of laravel but i also read that it is an insecure technique. So i need to solve this with .htaccess because i don´t have access to apache.

I have created a  .htaccess in the root dir but this just makes it work without the public name in URL but the routing inside laravel still shows the public name.
please help.
I try with others htaccess rules that remove complete the public but the internal routing off files like css, livewire, js doesn´t work because all of those have the public url.

```
<ifmodule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</ifmodule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php
```

Comment: point your web server at the public folder instead of the base of your project.  Instructions depend on your web server and if you are on shared host

Comment: thanks, im on a cloud server and i dont have access to apache. my URL is domain.com/cursos/public/panel
laravel is inside cursos and i want to show my url as somain.com/cursos/panel

Comment: Laravel is not really designed to run in a subfolder.  There will be quite a few things that you will need to fix.  Quicker and easier to get a better hosting provider

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I had to move the path that the domain is set to, to "public_html/public" instead of "public_html/". Then in your "public_html/public/.htaccess" file - I have the following settings:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```